# Android using ellipsize on widget text

Tags: android

I created a widget with text. I want to add ... to the end of the text where there is not enough place to show the whole text. I used   `android:ellipsize="end"` but only the first two rows are visible.

This is the widget layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="64dip"
    android:layout_height="72dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlayout">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
     android:layout_width="72dip" 
     android:layout_height="72dip"
     android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConfigInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"    
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first image is with the ellipsize effect. The second one is without it. You can see there is enough place to show more text.

[image]
I tried out in a 1x2 widget also, same happens

[image]

Thanks to Devunwired, I am now trying with this, but nothing has changed (I guess I am doing sg wrong)

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(); 
        final float densityMultiplier = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        final float scaledPx = 20 * densityMultiplier;
        paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
        final float size = paint.measureText(widgettext);  
        Log.i("size", size + "");  //1716 e.g

        while (widgettext != TextUtils.ellipsize(widgettext, paint, (float)GetDipsFromPixel(72),  TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)) { 
            paint.setTextSize(paint.getTextSize() - 1);
        }

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, widgettext);
        views.setTextColor(R.id.tvConfigInput, loadedtextcolor);

        views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", int_widgetfontsize);
```

Comment: What if you set `android:minLines` to 3, does it stop at 3 or does that fix the bug?

Comment: Do you still have the `android:ellipsize="end"` value in your XML.  That needs to go away if you are doing things manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found one of my favorite framework bugs: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254

Feel free to star it and hope that we see a fix for this soon.  The comments within also point to a number of solutions you can implement with a custom view to overcome the problem.  You can also manually place the ellipsis using a combination of `Paint.measureText()` and `TextUtils.ellipsize()`

HTH

Comment: It looks like this bug has been on for 3 yrs now. I liked your workaround the most, could you check what if I am doing wrong? Code is in the main post